# How to require Node Events module in React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native

How do I require the `events` Node module within my React Native project? I ran into some module dependency issues with `util` and `http` which I resolved by using Browserify to package.

I try to take the same approach with `events`:

```bash
npm install events
```

```js
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
```

After packaging with Browserify, I still get the same error from React Native: "Requiring unknown module 'events'."

Comment: Is this running on nodejs or in a browser?

Comment: It's actually running in React Native's environment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html#content

Comment: My guess is because `events` requires the function call as part of the initializer, you're going to run into trouble. Maybe try `var event = require('events'); eventEmitter = event.EventEmitter;`?

Comment: Yep, bundle file has been created. Works great with `util` and `http`.

Comment: Still no luck with `var event = require('events'); eventEmitter = event.EventEmitter;`

Comment: Is the events module actually getting bundled into the bundle file?

Comment: React Native has a built in event emitter FWIW

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1058

```
var EventEmitter = require('EventEmitter');
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `EventEmitter.js`

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')

const emitter = new EventEmitter()

export default emitter
```

Import it into your component:

```
import EventEmitter from '@/lib/EventEmitter'

EventEmitter.on('example', this.do_this)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using events and a bunch of other node core modules by using [react-native-webpack-server](https://github.com/mjohnston/react-native-webpack-server). It takes a bit of setup, but otherwise you're going to be running into the same problem with Buffer, assert, util, crypto, etc. Better take care of them all in one go.